# Batch image trace in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-trace, batch-processing

**Is there any way to batch trace images located in a directory with High fidelity option?**

I created an action including open an image, image trace it with high fidelity option, save it as `PDF` and close. However, when I batch do the tracing for images in a folder, the output is only black and white ones. I reckon the option setting action isn't captured when I create the action. So how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in Adobe Bridge CC.

**Instruction**

Drag your images into bridge - Select Them and then go to.. Tools/Illustrator/Image Trace

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We appreciate your answer, but we discourage footers and non-relevant links; it is considered bad form in SE.